# SQL Server: inline conditional convert with XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to convert data in plain text columns into xml columns. However, not all of the content is valid XML, so I need to ignore any rows with invalid XML. Is there a way I can filter out the invalid data either using some sort of inline conditional convert or something in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a version of the [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272%28SQL.90%29.aspx) function for XML data.

Regrettably no such built-in function exists - so you'll have to devise your own alternative, for which there are a couple of options:

If this is a one-off or small scale process for which performance isn't critical, you could process the input tables one row at a time inside a cursor, using a `TRY...CATCH` block to handle invalid casts (untested):

```
DECLARE xmlCur CURSOR FOR
SELECT textcol 
FROM inputTable

OPEN xmlCur
DECLARE @string nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @xml xml

FETCH NEXT FROM xmlCur into @string

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @xml = CAST(@string AS XML)
        -- Do something with XML
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- log failure/mark source row as invalid
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM xmlCur into @string
END

CLOSE xmlCur
DEALLOCATE xmlCur
```

Alternatively, if you're comfortable with .Net programming (and it's enabled on you server) you could use the [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to create your own IsXML function. The .Net code would need to be not much more complex than the third post on [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1166358.aspx).

The performance of the CLR solution may not be that much better than the cursor - you'd need to test to establish this.

(An obvious thing to try, which doesn't work, is a scalar-valued T-SQL function which attempts to cast the field to XML inside a `TRY...CATCH` block. However, `TRY...CATCH` is not permitted inside a function.)