# Computed columns in view's nested queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table with `nvarchar(max)` column that may contain xml of known structure. I'd like to parse it to perform some aggregations so need to filter out "bad" entries. Here is the test case:

```
create table TestTable ([Message] nvarchar(max))
insert into TestTable ([Message]) values 
    ('<root m="1"/>'),
    ('<root m="7"/>'),
    ('<rooo')
go

set quoted_identifier on
go   

create view TestView as
select data.value('(/root/@m)[1]', 'int') as MyValue
from (
    select cast([Message] as xml) as data
    from (
        select [Message] from dbo.TestTable where [Message] like '<root%>'
    ) as T1
) as T2
where data.exist('/root') = 1
go

select * from TestView
```

This produces:

> Msg 9400, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 5,
>   unexpected end of input

I don't understand why because if i run the nested query:

```
    select cast([Message] as xml) as data
    from (
        select [Message] from dbo.TestTable where [Message] like '<root%>'
    ) as T1
```

it perfectly returns 2 valid rows. Why??

p.s.
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: SQL Server can re-order expressions so there is no guarantee the `where [Message] like '<root%>'` happens first. You would need to put the potentially problematic expressions in a `CASE` statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL divide by zero encountered despite no columns containing 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0)

Comment: How is that possible if this breaks select semantics? Can my query be somehow rewritten to achieve what i need?

Comment: RE: Breaking `SELECT` semantics [this is discussed here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). Use `select  case when [Message] like '<root%>' then cast([Message] as xml) end as data`

Comment: Thanks, Martin! Can you please repost your comment as the answer and i'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not in the select clause but the where clause:

```
where data.exist('/root') = 1
```

I suspect you are thinking:  "Aha!  if the xml is not formatted properly then this will return 0 or NULL".  Nope, this function -- as with the other xml functions -- requires valid xml.  Or it gets an error.

You might be interested in [SQL Server: inline conditional convert with XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424164/sql-server-inline-conditional-convert-with-xml) and [In SQL Server, what is the best way to determine if a given string is a valid XML or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381864/ms-sql-server-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-given-string-is-a-valid-xm).

There does not appear to be a simple way to do what you want.  However, you might be able to do a simple check on the original string to see if it is reasonable xml.  For instance, the following checks if there are an equal number of "<" and ">":

```
select (case when len(replace(val, '<', '')) = len(replace(val, '>', ''))
             then 'MAYBE OKAY'
             else 'NOPE'
        end)
from (select '<badness' as val) t
```